# Не могу подключиться к базе Postgress на Python

Tags: python, sql, windows, postgresql

Коллеги, доброго. 
Пытаюсь подключиться к базе на Postgress на Python.
Код залезает в базу, и ищет сообщение по номеру телефона.
Вот код

```
  ith psycopg2.connect(dbname='', user='', password='', host='', port='', sslmode='') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM pfr WHERE xml_data LIKE '%+79169522420%'")

        record = cursor.fethall()

        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```

А вот лог

> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
>      psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed >    out (0x0000274C/10060)
>      Is the server running on host "172.18.0.89" and accepting
>      TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Между вами и сервером PostgreSQL есть Firewall? Telnet’ом пробовали подключиться?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо настроить [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

После добавления вашего хоста, выполните:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Если не поможет (а скорее всего не поможет) - смотрите в сторону порта из этого [мана](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html).

Comment: Я на винде сижу, к сожалению

Comment: Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Allow an app through Windows Firewall

Comment: И на будущее (это ни в коем случае не попытка сказать, что вы не умеете задавать вопросы), - вместо того, чтобы писать что делает код в БД, вы бы лучше указали ОС. Было бы более релевантно.

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с такой ошибкой, потому что сижу на pgadmin. Тот пароль, который указываете при входе в pgadmin укажите и в settings.py в DATABASES. Другого пароля он не примет. И заранее БД создайте, к примеру, в том же pgadmin. По умолчанию django будет стучатся к бд с названием postgres